# How to replace get_magic_quotes_runtime() in PHP7.4

Tags: php, deprecated

The function `get_magic_quotes_runtime` is deprecated in PHP 7.4 as per documantation.

> This function has been DEPRECATED as of PHP 7.4.0. Relying on this function is highly discouraged.

How to replace it with a valid code with the same functionality?

A particular example [PunBB](https://punbb.informer.com/) v1.4.5, file: common.php line 18:

```php
// Turn off magic_quotes_runtime
if (get_magic_quotes_runtime()) {
    @ini_set('magic_quotes_runtime', false);
}
```

Comment: "Returns 0 if magic_quotes_runtime is off, 1 otherwise. Or always returns FALSE as of PHP 5.4.0."  (according to the docs)

Comment: Also, it is bad practise to put `@` in front of functions, it is better you actually solve the errors generated rather than simply hiding them under the carpet `;-)`

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Well it is a reference to `magic_quotes_runtime` which is itself deprecated as of [***PHP 5.3 and REMOVED in PHP 5.4***](https://www.php.net/manual/en/info.configuration.php#ini.magic-quotes-runtime) so you have no need to use `get_magic_quotes_runtime` in PHP 7.4

So you can simply update your code accordingly:

```
/***
 * Turn off magic_quotes_runtime
 * this function serves no purpose
if (get_magic_quotes_runtime()) {
    @ini_set('magic_quotes_runtime', false);
}
***/
```

*Edit: This is just an example, you can simply delete your shown code `;-)`*

Answer (score 4):

The proper way to replace it is to not use. You can do that by

```
if(version_compare(PHP_VERSION, '7.4.0', '<') && get_magic_quotes_runtime()) {
    @set_magic_quotes_runtime(0);
}
```

Comment: Thanks! Needed to start conversion of older code and this solution got me out of the woods:)

Answer (score 1):

`magic_quotes_runtime` always returns `false` as of `PHP 5.4.0`, has been DEPRECATED as of `PHP 7.4.0`, and REMOVED as of `PHP 8.0.0`. The proper way is to not use it in the newest versions:

```
// get_magic_quotes_runtime
$mqr = false;
if (version_compare(PHP_VERSION, '5.4.0', '<')) {
  $mqr = get_magic_quotes_runtime();
}

...

// set_magic_quotes_runtime
$mqr = true;
if (version_compare(PHP_VERSION, '5.4.0', '<')) {
  set_magic_quotes_runtime($mqr); 
}
```